# Changing urls in apache 2.2

Tags: php, url, ubuntu, apache2

I have an apache 2.2 and php5 server running on ubuntu 10.10.  I am trying to make a url /anything/page.php change to /page.php?var=anything.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache `mod_rewrite` then you can set something like this in your Apache conf file or in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/page.php$ /page.php?var=$1
```

see more [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)